# Display different container by clicking select fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple select dropdown menu.

```
<select onchange="showDiv(this)">
      <option value="1">Container 01</option>
      <option value="2">Container 01 + 02</option>
      <option value="3">Container 01 + 02 + 03</option>
</select>
```

I have three container. If I click in the select area  on  "container 01 + 02", container 1 and 2 should appear. If I click on "container 01", only container 01 appears.

```
  <div id="container_01></div>
  <div id="container_02></div>
  <div id="container_03></div>
```

I have found a way to do this using Jquery:

```
function showDiv(select){
   if(select.value==1){
    document.getElementById('container_01').style.display = "block";
   } 
    else if (select.value==2){
    document.getElementById('container_01').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('container_02').style.display = "block";
   } 
    else if(select.value==3){
    document.getElementById('container_01').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('container_02').style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById('container_03').style.display = "block";
   }
```

This works fine for me!

**Now my Problem:**

To make the select fields more attractive, I'm using a pretty nice script, to pep up the selection. Here an example:
https://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/index3.html

The thing is, the script converts the select dropdown menu to a list element:

```
<ul>
  <li class="" data-value="1"> <span>1</span> </li>
  <li class="cs-selected" data-value="2"> <span>2</span> </li>
  <li class="" data-value="3"> <span>3</span> </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible, to rebuilt the effect, I have created for the select menu? 
Get the **data-value** from **li.cs-selected** and display:

```
<div id="container_01></div>
<div id="container_02></div>
```

Im not pretty good at Javascript. Maybe someone can help me out, to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your aim is to get the class of List element selected, for that use this:

```
var elementSelected = document.getElementByClassName('your_class_name');
```

Upon storing a reference in `elementSelected` apply an event listener as:

```
elementSelected.onClick = function(){ //Code goes here }
```

OR you could use `addEventListener` method to do the same:

```
elementSelected.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    alert('something');
}, false);
```

Once the element is clicked you can get its value by using

`var elementValue = elementSelected.value`

Then you can transfer that value into the "select-option" drop down menu you've created.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have or can use jQuery but you can use this script to get that values without needing select.

```
// I would add a classname or an id to differentiate from other ul tags. 
$('ul.myMenuSelect').on('click', 'li', function(){
   var value = $(this).data('value');
   $(this).addClass('cs-selected').siblings().removeClass('cs-selected');
   $('#container_' + value).show().siblings().hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li.cs-selected").attr("data-value")
```